# Cache/offline website script

Tags: php, caching, static

I have created a simple cms to build simple websites for my customers. The cms is database-driven. I would like to make a offline/cache/static copy of the websites, to increase performance.

Is there any php script available, that traverses a website and creates a static version?

Comment: Why PHP? Won't wget or httrack do?

Comment: I would like to automate it, so the user can start the process by pressing "Publish" within the cms. That is why I was hoping for PHP (the cms is developed with PHP).

Comment: @Eydun my solution would allow this approach

Answer (score 1):

Make one yourself and integrate it into your simple CMS?

There is a lot of possibilities which you can use like [Memcache](http://php.net/memcache), [APC](http://php.net/apc) and just plain static files generated by your application.

Your question is pretty vague since you haven't provided any real problems with writing your cache. But besides the two first options I mentioned, a simple static file cache can be accomplished with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents), [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) and [filemtime](http://php.net/filemtime)

Example (loose):

```
<?php


if( file_exists("/cache_dir/".$page_name) && (time() - filemtime("/cache_dir/".$page_name)) > 300)
{
  $contents = file_get_contens("/cache_dir/".$page_name);
}
else
{
  // getting the page contents
  ob_start();

  //output your page

  $contents = ob_get_clean();
  file_put_contens($contents, "/cache_dir/".$page_name);
}

echo $contents;

?>
```

It's a short and loosely created example but it might help you get an idea how to make a solution that fits your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do many things to optimize the sites, most do not traverse the site and create a cache, you could write your own class which is quite simple or you could use one already written:

http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/02/18/simple-file-based-php-cache-class/

The way it would work is the first time someone visits the live page create a cache if the cache does not exist if however the cache does exist serve up the cache version

Comment: If you are going to be using full page caching it would make sense to use `ob_start();`, `ob_get_contents();` and `ob_end_clean();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

Caching, especially when it's offline, is done by most modern browsers automatically.  Since PHP is a server-side language, it's restricted to only effect stuff on the "online" end.  If you want to increase performance though, you can try automatically [minifying](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) your resources via PHP.

If you're super-intent on storing data offline, you could see what you can fit into cookies, but I don't really see that as a conventional method.

EDIT:

If you mean making static pages on the server side, then yes. With the right permissions, you can create and edit pages with fopen() and [related functions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php).